# Setting WMQ_CCDTURL in XMS and unmanaged mode doesn't work

Tags: ibm-mq, xms

I did a lot of reseach, and I'm stuck at a later phase now in our implementation as client ...

In short the requirements are:

- SSL
- Client app does Load-balancing. We need separate CCDT files in one application so we can handle all connections ourselves.
- Unmanaged mode is used for SSL
- XMS is used for asynchronous automatic consumption of incoming messages instead of polling the queue
- IBM MQ Client V8.0.0.5 is used
- We connect to 4 QMs. Everything is the same in the 4 connections except the port. QM name is '*'.

To configure separate CCDT files we can configure `XMSC.WMQ_CCDTURL`, but in unmanaged mode this is ingored. If I only change the connection mode to CLIENT mode (CT_WMQ) then it looks in the right configured directory. But when using unmanaged mode, this property is ignored.

This question is also asked here: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=0268e8f5-8562-4b28-a621-32e20dee0c53

I try same settings, once with client mode and once with unmanaged mode. Event viewer gives different output related to CCDT. In unmanaged mode it looks for the default location.

- Client mode event viewer event: http://pasted.co/27db600f (CCDT does not exist but it looks in the right directory which is good)
- Unmanaged mode event viewer event: http://pasted.co/d5979a2c

Please help in setting separate CCDTURLs for these 4 separate connections. Don't ask me to use one CCDT with all the defined connection in it, that's not what we want because we want to do the load-balancing ourselves.

Comment: I thought CCDTURL was added in V9 but it might be different in XMS. Have you tried using a V9 client?

Comment: @MoragHughson Tried with latest version. Nothing changes... I can't create a PMR because we have no customer ID. If someone can do this for me, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: this is interesting also: [Fix IT06084](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IT06084). But this should be already included in 9.0.5 (I hope)?

Comment: That APAR was released with 8.0.0.4 which was out before 9.0.0.0 was released so would(should) have been included in any thing 9.0.0.0 and higher, but that is also a APAR related to IBM MQ Classes for Java so would not related to your XMS.NET issue.